# display the word in the selected spinner in the textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, spinner

I try to explain by showing as many examples as possible, I chose a word from the spinner, for example it is "cat", after I select it in the spinner i.e. after I click it should also appear in the textview.

Spinner click "cat"
TextView change "cat"

I again click Spinner "dog"
TextView change "dog"

now my not full code:

````
```Spinner sababspinner = findViewById(R.id.Sababspinner);
    sababspinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
````

}```

- all spinner texts in string.xml

Comment: Add a code for what you have done.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: in OnItemSelected add list[position] and set it's value to textview

Comment: please give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) with your spinner dataset, then in the `onItemSelected` method write something like `textView.setText(dataset.get(position))`.